# не запускаются виртуальные машины VirtualBox

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox

При запуске какой либо виртуальной машины выдаётся ошибка :

```
Виртуальная машина неожиданно прервалась во время запуска с кодом выхода 1 (0x1).
```

Система Win7

Пытался запустить Arch Linux (1.5ГБ RAM) и Win95 (128MБ RAM)

Comment: Какой проц на хосте и включена ли виртуализация в биосе?

Comment: @donRumata ,  процессор AMD A4 .Как проверить включина ли виртуализация ? Утилита от AMD пишет " эта система AMD64 сочетает в себе виртуализацию AMD, высокую производительность и энергоэффективность "

Comment: В БИОС должно быть чё-то со словом "virtualization" или `svm`. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F